# OnTrigger && Collisions not being Detected Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, physics

I understand this question has been asked a lot, but I haven't been able to find a solution on my own, I'm simply trying to shoot a projectile from a gun, and a function being run when the projectile collides with an enemy. The Debug Log also has not been told to write "has Collided"

Here's the script on the projectile as well as the movement that its using:

```
<pre><code>
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class iceShard : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IEnumerator changeSpeed;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Debug.Log("has Collided");
            changeSpeed = ChangeSpeed(other.transform.GetComponent<Enemy>().enemySpeed);

            StartCoroutine(changeSpeed);
        }

    }
    private IEnumerator ChangeSpeed(float enemySpeed)
    {
        enemySpeed = enemySpeed / 2;
        Debug.Log(enemySpeed);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);

        enemySpeed = enemySpeed * 2;
        Debug.Log(enemySpeed);


    }
}

using Obscure.SDC;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class OrbMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    Crosshair cs;
    Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField]private int orbSpeed = 40;
    [SerializeField] private Transform firePoint;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;

        cs = GameObject.Find("Crosshair").GetComponent<Crosshair>();
        firePoint = GameObject.Find("OrbSpawnPos").GetComponent<Transform>();



        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce((cs.GetHitPoint() - firePoint.position).normalized * orbSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);

    }
 
}

</code></pre>
```

```
   I also have pictures of things that might be causing the problem:
```

[Collision Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tM3XO.png)

[ProjectilePrefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfnfj.png)

[EnemyPrefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTEM2.png)

Ty to anyone who reads this  In my efforts to resolve the issue of collision detection not functioning properly in Unity's first-person perspective, I experimented with various potential solutions. I encountered a problem where collisions were not being detected as expected, and I undertook several troubleshooting steps to address this.  Initially, I focused on examining the configuration of the colliders associated with the first-person character or camera. Since the camera serves as the viewpoint for the player in a first-person perspective, it was crucial to ensure that its collider was accurately aligned and properly sized to represent the player's presence in the game world. I meticulously checked the collider's parameters, such as its position, size, and shape, to verify that they were appropriately set.  Additionally, I paid close attention to the presence of rigidbodies && box colliders attached to the relevant game objects. I experimented with the istrigger option && isKinematic settings. I also tried to tweak the project settings and layer collisions

Comment: you need to show the code you used to move things, a picture of the setup of the moving thing, a picture of the thing you think it should be hitting..

Collision requires physics, you cant just do transform.<anything> to move it. You also need rigidibodies and the collision matrix to be set to collilde, so.. check again ..

Comment: @BugFinder I do have pictures of the setuos if the projectile & the enemy. I have implemeted the advice you have about showing the script that moves the object although i still haven't found the solution yet. Ty for the help though.

Comment: the trigger method in iceshard is not called because that script is not on the orb, nor enemy or anything else demonstrated

Comment: @BugFinder If you look near the bottom in the projectile prefab image I provided, the ice shard script is presemt at the bottom of the inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine at first look. Only thing I can think of is, the object is not colliding with enemy. Try to put the debug outside the if statement to see if OnTriggerEnter is called and print out the other object.

Set the collision detection to discrete in both the enemy and orb. May be different settings in both is causing the issue. Also, if the orb is moving very fast the collision may not be detected.